# Exception: Cannot bind to the target method because its signature or security transparency is not compatible with that of the delegate type

Tags: c#, wpf, delegates

```
        Type objectType = Application.Current.MainWindow.GetType();
            EventInfo CtrlEventInfo = objectType.GetEvent(strEventName);
            if (CtrlEventInfo == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            Type TypeDelegate = CtrlEventInfo.EventHandlerType;
            MethodInfo methodInfo = typeof(MyPOS.Controls.ActiveAccounts.ViewCtrl).GetMethod(strMethodName, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
            Delegate DelHandler = Delegate.CreateDelegate(TypeDelegate, this, methodInfo);
            CtrlEventInfo.AddEventHandler(Application.Current.MainWindow, DelHandler);
```

Cannot bind to the target method because its signature or security transparency is not compatible with that of the delegate type

is thrown in line

```
Delegate DelHandler = Delegate.CreateDelegate(TypeDelegate, this, methodInfo);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to change your code to

```
 MyPOS.Controls.ActiveAccounts.ViewCtrl obj= new MyPOS.Controls.ActiveAccounts.ViewCtrl();
 Delegate DelHandler = Delegate.CreateDelegate(TypeDelegate, obj, methodInfo);
```